# High precision in training and validation but low precision in test

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

**Hi to everyone!!**

I have a problem with my model.
I am training a CNN with transfer learning using the MobileNet base model.
My dataset is made up of 3 classes "paper, scissors, rock" (8751 images, and all class are perfectly balanced) and I use it to create a hand gesture recognition model for the "paper, scissors, rock" game.

In the training phase with keras I get excellent results both with the training set and with the test set (accuracy, precision, AUC all more or less on 0.98%):
[image: This is the last epochs]
This is the last epochs.

When I go to use the validation set, these metrics have a very low result:
[image: This is the validation-set score]

I think this could be due to overfitting and that I should do some tuning on my model, in fact through augmentation I increase the number of images in my dataset and then I try to modify the base model of the MobileNet by adding layers.

But things are not getting better ... Can you help me? I'm going crazy.
This is my model training code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras
from keras.metrics import Precision, Recall

from collections import Counter

IMAGE_SIZE = (224, 224)
IMG_SHAPE = IMAGE_SIZE + (3,)
TRAIN_DATASET_DIR = "/content/PAPER_SCISSOR_ROCK/TRAIN"
TEST_DATASET_DIR = "/content/PAPER_SCISSOR_ROCK/TEST"
NUM_CLASSES = 3
BATCH_SIZE = 16
EPOCHS = 40
FC_LAYERS = [512, 512, 256, 256]
DROPOUT = 0.4
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    vertical_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.20,
    rescale=1. / 255, 
    fill_mode = 'wrap',
    rotation_range = 45,
    brightness_range=[0.2,1.0]
    #brightness_range=[1, 2],
    #preprocessing_function = keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input
)

# ONLY FOR TEST, SPLITT IN VALIDATION AND TEST IMAGES (TO CALCULATE PRECSION AND CONFUSION MATRIX AFTER)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    validation_split=0.3
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DATASET_DIR,
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)

val_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_DATASET_DIR,
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset='training',
    shuffle=True
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_DATASET_DIR,
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode="categorical",
    subset="validation",
    shuffle=True
)

def build_finetune_model(base_model, dropout, fc_layers, num_classes):
    # prevents weights from being updated in a given layer during training.
    for layer in base_model.layers:
      layer.trainable = False
    # THE NEW PART SUGGESTED
    for layer in base_model.layers[-30:]: 
      layer.trainable=True 
     
    for layer in base_model.layers:
      if "BatchNormalization" in layer.__class__.__name__:
        layer.trainable = False

    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    for fc in fc_layers:
      print(fc)
      x = Dense(fc, activation='relu')(x)
      x = Dropout(dropout)(x)
    preditions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    finetune_model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = preditions)
    return finetune_model

mobielNetV2 = tensorflow.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')


finetune_model = build_finetune_model(mobielNetV2, dropout = DROPOUT, fc_layers = FC_LAYERS, num_classes = NUM_CLASSES)


finetune_model.compile(tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy', 'AUC', Precision(), Recall()])

# Imposed EarlyStopping, in any era in which the model is seen to overfit, it stops.
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto')
r = finetune_model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, epochs=EPOCHS, steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator)/BATCH_SIZE,
              validation_steps=len(test_generator), callbacks=[es])
print("\nSAVE THE MODEL")

finetune_model.save(f"/content/drive/My Drive/Computer_Vision/Models/MobileNet_ScissorPaperRock_{EPOCHS}_epochs.h5")
```

**EDITED**

This is the code about how I calculate the precision, recall and f1-scor of validation set:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# test_steps_per_epoch = np.math.ceil(val_generator.samples / val_generator.batch_size)
# print(test_steps_per_epoch)

predictions = finetune_model.predict(val_generator)
# Get most likely class
predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1) 
print(val_generator, len(val_generator))
# Get ground-truth classes and class-labels
true_classes = val_generator.classes
#print(true_classes)
class_labels = list(val_generator.class_indices.keys())
#print(class_labels)

# Use scikit-learn to get statistics
report = classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)
```

Comment: Most likely this is due to `shuffle = True` parameter. Set it `False` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fine-tuning a MobileNet V2 model, then it is a good idea to update the weights of the last few layers. MobileNet V2 is trained to classify 1000 differnet classes, but your domain contains only 3 classes of similar features. The first few layers are usually used for the general features, while the last few layers are less general, and those would affect your model the most since your domain is a lot smaller. I'd suggest that you allow the last 20%-30% layers of MobileNet V2 to update weights.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer!! How can I take the llast layer of the MobileNet model?

Comment: Is this the correct way to take the last layer??
for layer in base_model.layers[:30]:
      layer.trainable=True

Comment: Hi, yes but in the code that you wrote here you are training the first 30 layers not the last, what you actually should do is : for layer in base_model.layers[-30:]: layer.trainable=True

Comment: If I try to train the last layer I obtain this error: 
"Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function" and I think is about the label

Comment: That's strange, I will try to load your code to my machine and try it for myself to make sure that what I said is valid. Anyways, it is not a very good idea to train the first few layers without training the other layers with them.

Comment: Maybe you should also try to allow all of the layers to be trainable for example.

Comment: Yes I try to train all layer and I obtain the same error...

Comment: I think tis is an error of Google Colab (I use it)...if I train the  model with my original code this crash... :O

Comment: usually this works for me:
for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
  layer.trainable =  False

Comment: Is there any more details for the error message, I really can't figure out anything out of this.

Comment: Now the code run well...I think was an error by Colab.
But I obtain the same result.
In the code post here I have add the new code suggested by you (there is a comment "# THE NEW PART SUGGESTED") and the code about how I calculate the precision, recall and f1-score of val set

Comment: The solution is use the shuffle=False in ImageDataGenerator. I also use your suggestion

Comment: OK, Great.  Good Luck!